# Assembly x86 movsb

Tags: video, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm creating a two stages bootloader,the second stage uses 13h(320x200) video mode.I decided to start writing a simple function to copy a double buffer to the video memory,the problem is nothing seems to be copied,the code:

```
org 0x7E00
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax

jmp begin

foo: times 400 db 5

govideo:
mov ah, 0
mov al, 13h
int 10h
ret

begin:
call govideo

mov ax, 0xa000 ; video memory address
mov es, ax     ; es,address to receive
mov di, 0x0    ; no offset
mov ax, foo    ; foo,the test double buffer,all bytes initialized with 5(red color)
mov ds, ax     ; ds,address to copy 
mov si, 0x0    ; no offset
mov cx, 400    ; all foo 400 bytes
cld            ; clear direction flag,so es and ds get incremented
rep movsb      ; copy all 400 bytes

terminate:
times 510-($-$$) db 0
```

This code should fill the first 400 bytes of the video memory with the red color,but nothing happens.Although the following code does the job(but i need memory to memory),

```
mov ax, 0xa000
mov es, ax
mov al, 5
mov cx, 400
cld
rep stosb
```

Why the first snippet doesn't work?

Thanks in advance

Edit 2:Moving directly to si and di:

```
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
mov ds, ax

mov di, 0xa000
mov si, foo

mov cx, 400
cld
rep movsb
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `mov ax, seg foo` ?

Comment: @Michael i didn't understood what you meant!

Comment: You're currently doing `mov ax, foo` / `mov ds,ax`, which will put the _offset_ of `foo` in `ds`. Seems to me like you'd want the _segment_  of `foo`. Hence the suggestion to use `seg foo`.

Comment: I started learning assembly weeks ago,so i don't have 100% of sure on what i'm doing but from what i read 'movsb' moves a byte from the address stored in [ds:si] to the address stored in [es:si],also your suggestion gave me an error

Comment: By doing 'mov ax, foo'/'mov ds, ax' my intention was to put foo address in ds

Comment: @Michael thanks for your help,after Mika pointed this link explaining the usage of 'seg' i comprehended what you meant.

Comment: @Mateus:The "movsb"-instruction get the byte from the address in DS:SI and store it in the address of ES:DI. And for your second snippet with stosb also ES:DI are used.

Comment: I thought 12h was planar 640x480 mode?  You can't just mov into memory for planar modes, there's more to it.  Did you mean (flat) mode 13h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving address of foo directly to segment register. As you probably already know, segment registers are used to hold 20-bit address that is added to the offset. In your case address of foo is something like 0x7E06. When you move this to segment register and zero out the offset, you get address 0x7E06 << 4 + 0 = 0x7E060.

For this case you can use [seg](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall02/V22.0201-001/nasm_doc_html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.6) as Michael pointed out in the comments:

```
mov ax, seg foo
mov ds, ax
```

Or alternatively:

```
mov ax, foo
shr ax, 4
mov ds, ax
```

Note that you also have to adjust index register accordingly if your address is not multiple of 16.

Comment: Thanks!Shifting the register worked for me,when i tried the SEG method i got this error:'binary output format does not support segment base references'

Comment: Just one more doubt.I tried moving the address of foo directly to SI,but it didn't worked.Considering that foo address can be represented in 16 bits(ex:0x7E06),shouldn't it work?

Comment: Moving directly to SI should work if you clear the segment register. About SEG not working, you might also want to try `mov ax, foo >> 4`.

Comment: I tried clearing DS but it doesn't work!I'll edit the question.

Comment: Now you cleared both es and ds. Your es:di should still point to 0xA0000.